# UIBarButtonItem design change doesn't work the first time but the second

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uibarbuttonitem

I want to change the design of my `UIBarButtonItem` and it works somewhat with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"]  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

The problem is that the first time the app loads the background image of the button doesn't change, but if I leave the view and come back the background is changed to what I want. What vould be the issue here? I use storyboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with `UIAppearance` you should set the appearance of the control before view is getting loaded or the control is created. If you are creating the control programmatically you can do like (sample code)

```
 [[UIStepper appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc]init];
 [self.view addSubview: stepper];
```

or try to set the appearance  in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

From `UIAppearance.h`

> To customize the appearances for instances of a class contained within an instance of a container class, or instances in a hierarchy, use +appearanceWhenContainedIn: for the appropriate appearance proxy. For example:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTintColor:myNavBarColor];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], [UIPopoverController class], nil] setTintColor:myPopoverNavBarColor];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolbar class], nil] setTintColor:myToolbarColor];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolbar class], [UIPopoverController class], nil] setTintColor:myPopoverToolbarColor];
```

Comment: There we go! Thank you man! New lesson learned, but how can I do this if I want to change the appearance during the cause of the run?

Comment: Change the appearance before going to that view. suppose you have two View controllers VC1 and VC2. set the appearance of button in VC2 from VC1. i never tried but hop it wil work

Comment: I have the same issue in iOS 7. I setup my appearance in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` before I initiate anything. But my UIBarButtonItems don't show background images. The textcolor works though...

Answer (score 0):

Call your code before you init a class - outside of the class.